# Loading Bootstrap from CDN with Require.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, cdn

Bootstrap is distributed in CDN in

http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

- Is it possible to load Bootstrap with Require.JS 2.x (shimmed or native AMD)?
- How it is possible to load Bootstrap, or any minified JS, directly from CDN URL with Require.js

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
requirejs.config({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: { 
        /* Load jquery from google cdn. On fail, load local file. */
        'jquery': ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min', 'libs/jquery-min'],
        /* Load bootstrap from cdn. On fail, load local file. */
        'bootstrap': ['//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.', 'libs/bootstrap-min']
    },
    shim: {
        /* Set bootstrap dependencies (just jQuery) */
        'bootstrap' : ['jquery']
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($) {
    console.log("Loaded :)");    
    return {};
});
```

Comment: Great! Any pointer what's //netnda protocol thing? HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: Exactly! Relative protocol... Thats works too in script or img tags <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa bootstrapcdn.com supports http & https