# How to use javascript and PHP to import data Fuel UX datagrid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

Fuel UX is here:
http://exacttarget.github.com/fuelux/

Specifically i'm trying to use the Datagrid.

Here's an example:
http://code.exacttarget.com/code-examples/datagrid.html

I've attempted to recreated this:
https://raw.github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/master/sample/data.js

And just output it through the PHP file.  I was able to get PHP to correctly output the correct data and just dumped it into the main file so the data.js file is now output in the main PHP/HTML file with all my information in the header using these tags:

```
<script></script>
```

And used the sample markup from the GitHub website.

I can't seem to get it to work correctly, is there another way to import data from PHP to the datagrid?  Should some of the code for the data.js be changed since it is now being output in the main php/html file?

Basically attempting to pull data from MySQL using PHP and then dump it into a data grid.  I can't seem to find much documentation and I guess my real question would be what is the best way to import data from my php application into the Fuel UX Datagrid?

Comment: It seems to me your approach is solid but it is possible you'd need to make some slight adjustments, as you suggest.  Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?  Could you post a sample of your version of the data.js?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I have followed their tutorial to the letter as far as i can see, also using requirejs, underscorejs, using the data.js and datasource.js file which they use on their example page to try and replicate the example but nothing shows up in my datagrid, no errores in the console no nothing. I'm clueless atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>With php / mysql write to data.js, use sample/data.js as an example. (or rename your .php to data.js and parse as php ([Parse js/css as a PHP file using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722375/parse-js-css-as-a-php-file-using-htaccess))).</strike>

[setting fuelux datagrid source from backbone collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744861/setting-fuelux-datagrid-source-from-backbone-collection) gives the right direction.

Presume you got a data databases table with the fields: id, title and city and you want to show this in the datagrid.

Create php file which return json format from your mysql (example):

**data.php:**

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('report_errors','on');
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '*******', 'cities');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$data = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT `id`,`title`,`city` FROM `poi`')) 
{

        //$data['testdata'] = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        while(($row=$result->fetch_assoc())){$data[]=$row;}
        $result->close();
}


header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

create a static datasource **testdatasource.js**:

```
/*
 * Fuel UX Data components - static data source
 * https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux-data
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012 ExactTarget
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */

(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['underscore'], factory);
    } else {
        root.TestDataSource = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {

    var TestDataSource = function (options) {
        this._formatter = options.formatter;
        this._columns = options.columns;
        this._delay = options.delay || 0;
    };

    TestDataSource.prototype = {

        columns: function () {
            return this._columns;
        },

        data: function (options, callback) {
            var self = this;

            setTimeout(function () {
                var data;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/data.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(result) {
                        data = result;
                    }
                });

                                    // SEARCHING
                if (options.search) {
                    data = _.filter(data, function (item) {
                        var match = false;

                        _.each(item, function (prop) {
                            if (_.isString(prop) || _.isFinite(prop)) {
                                if (prop.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(options.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) match = true;
                            }
                        });

                        return match;
                    });
                }


                var count = data.length;

                // SORTING
                if (options.sortProperty) {
                    data = _.sortBy(data, options.sortProperty);
                    if (options.sortDirection === 'desc') data.reverse();
                }

                // PAGING
                var startIndex = options.pageIndex * options.pageSize;
                var endIndex = startIndex + options.pageSize;
                var end = (endIndex > count) ? count : endIndex;
                var pages = Math.ceil(count / options.pageSize);
                var page = options.pageIndex + 1;
                var start = startIndex + 1;

                data = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

                if (self._formatter) self._formatter(data);

                callback({ data: data, start: start, end: end, count: count, pages: pages, page: page });

            }, this._delay)
        }
    };

    return TestDataSource;
}));
```

This builds a data set from data.php `$.ajax({
                        url: '/data.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(result) {
                            data = result;
                        }
                    });`

In your html call your data set and create the columns:

```
var dataSource = new TestDataSource({
columns: [
{
property: 'id',
label: 'ID',
sortable: true
},
{
property: 'title',
label: 'Title',
sortable: true
},
{
property: 'city',
label: 'City',
sortable: true
}
],
delay: 250
});
```

Initialize the grid grid with this data source:

```
$('#MyGrid').datagrid({
dataSource: dataSource
});
```

## Get the datagrid working:

1. download the source (zip) from and extract to /fuelux-master/
2. create /index.html

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="fuelux">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fuel UX 2</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="./fuelux-master/dist/css/fuelux.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="./fuelux-master/lib/require.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
padding-bottom: 200px;
}
</style>

<script>
requirejs.config({
paths: {
'jquery': './fuelux-master/lib/jquery',
'underscore': 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min',
'bootstrap': './fuelux-master/lib/bootstrap/js',
'fuelux': './fuelux-master/src',
'sample': './fuelux-master/sample'
}
});

require(['jquery', 'sample/data', 'sample/datasource', 'sample/datasourceTree', 'fuelux/all'], 


function ($, sampleData, StaticDataSource,datasourceTree) {


// DATAGRID
var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
columns: [
{
property: 'toponymName',
label: 'Name',
sortable: true
},
{
property: 'countrycode',
label: 'Country',
sortable: true
},
{
property: 'population',
label: 'Population',
sortable: true
},
{
property: 'fcodeName',
label: 'Type',
sortable: true
}
],
data: sampleData.geonames,
delay: 250
});

$('#MyGrid').datagrid({
dataSource: dataSource
});

});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">


<!-- DATAGRID -->
<table id="MyGrid" class="table table-bordered datagrid">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>
<span class="datagrid-header-title">Geographic Data Sample</span>

<div class="datagrid-header-left">
<div class="input-append search datagrid-search">
<input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Search">
<button class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="datagrid-header-right">
<div class="select filter" data-resize="auto">
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
<span class="dropdown-label"></span>
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li data-value="all" data-selected="true"><a href="#">All</a></li>
<li data-value="lt5m"><a href="#">Population &lt; 5M</a></li>
<li data-value="gte5m"><a href="#">Population &gt;= 5M</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>
<div class="datagrid-footer-left" style="display:none;">
<div class="grid-controls">
<span>
<span class="grid-start"></span> -
<span class="grid-end"></span> of
<span class="grid-count"></span>
</span>
<div class="select grid-pagesize" data-resize="auto">
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
<span class="dropdown-label"></span>
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li data-value="5" data-selected="true"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li data-value="10"><a href="#">10</a></li>
<li data-value="20"><a href="#">20</a></li>
<li data-value="50"><a href="#">50</a></li>
<li data-value="100"><a href="#">100</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<span>Per Page</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="datagrid-footer-right" style="display:none;">
<div class="grid-pager">
<button type="button" class="btn grid-prevpage"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></button>
<span>Page</span>

<div class="input-append dropdown combobox">
<input class="span1" type="text">
<button class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="caret"></i></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
</div>
<span>of <span class="grid-pages"></span></span>
<button type="button" class="btn grid-nextpage"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

see **./fuelux-master/** in the paths of the requirejs config. Also see the initializations of `var dataSource` to define your columns. At least you needto write the full html of the table with id="MyGrid".

Some refactoring and use of CDNs example: http://plnkr.co/hZRjry5vG8ZcOG4VbjNq

- use bootstrap and jQuery via CDN with requirejs, see [Loading Bootstrap from CDN with Require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464846/loading-bootstrap-from-cdn-with-require-js)
- replace the include of all.js with datagrid.js (**note** the datagrid won't work without select.js and util.js is required for select.js)
- remove sample/datasourceTree cause we don't need it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up deciding I needed to learn javascript, specifically Node.js .... a month+ later and I can't imagine using PHP for any future projects and importing couldn't be easier .... it was just my lack of knowledge that was hindering me from being able to do this .... but now it's so easy I laugh at how much time I spent trying to figure it out.  Thanks for the reply!