# RequireJs all modules loaded properly in browser but script not working

Tags: jquery, requirejs, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm new in **RequireJs**. I'm using Bootstrap 4. I found `console` error with **RequireJs** and `Bootstrapjs` with `ajax`.

[image]

If I `inspect element` using firebug then I see all files are load correctly.

[image]

> HTML code

```
<script data-main="js/signupconfig" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

> signupconfig.js

```
requirejs(['./main'], function (main) {
    requirejs(['app/signup']);
});
```

> main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jqueryslim: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min',
        jquerymin: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min',
        tether: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min',
        bootstrapmin: 'bootstrap.min'
    }
});
```

> signup.js

```
define (['jqueryslim', 'jquerymin', 'tether', 'bootstrapmin'], function (){});
```

> file structure

`js
    app
        signup.js
    lib
        bootstrap.min.js
    require.js
    main.js`

I don't understand what I missing. I seen **stackoverflow** has [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130892/twitter-bootstrap-js-file-loaded-but-not-working-alongside-requirejs) question already. But I'm thinking difference. If local file isn't working like my code then other local file will not work.

> Note: I don't want `CDN` link solution for `bootstrap js`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap js file loaded but not working alongside requirejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130892/twitter-bootstrap-js-file-loaded-but-not-working-alongside-requirejs)

Comment: It does not matter whether you want to load from a CDN or not. The answer in that other question has the solution to your problem: you must use a `shim` settings.

Comment: `CDN` solution isn't working with bootstap 4 because of `tether.min.js`. I'm thinking about the `shim` setting.