# Using local d3.js in IPython

Tags: d3.js, requirejs, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm having issue trying to run d3.js in my IPYthon session on a computer with no Internet access.

I have put a copy of the latest d3.js library in my folder and used this code ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367591/how-to-add-external-javascript-file-in-ipython-notebook))

```
%%javascript

requirejs.config({
    paths: { 
        'd3': ['//localhost:9876/notebooks/notebook/Sandboxes/d3'], 
    },
});

require(['d3'], function(d3) {
    console.log("Loaded :)");    
    return {};
});
```

Nothing happens in the console yet I know that this url works as :

```
import requests as r
r.get("http://localhost:9876/notebooks/notebook/Sandboxes/d3.js").text
```

returns the file.

On a side note, when I try getting the file via wget

```
 wget localhost:9876/notebooks/notebook/Sandboxes/d3.js
```

It downloads 470070 o (the correct size) but does not complete...

Thanks for any possible answer,
naingenieu

BTW: I use 
ipython v3.0.0
python 2.7.9 (anaconda 2.2.0)
on a redhat server

Comment: Can you give information about the computer? Also, about the IPython, Python version.

Comment: Yep, I added the informations