# ngSanitize module inject error

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I am trying to use **angular-sanitize** in angularJS.

I require angular-sanitize and inject it in my module.

But i get the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: f.module(...).provider(...).info is not a function
>
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

app.js

```
const angular_sanitize = require('angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js');  

var app = angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
```

It works if i am using a script in index.html, but i want it to work as a module dependency instead.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: with `require()` you shouldn't have to include the extension (.js)

Comment: i have also tried without the js... still same problem

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue, not sure if the same fix but might help..
so.. in bower.json I had "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.5" and on bower install it pulled the latest version 1.6.4 which has breaking changes for my installed angular version 1.5.9..
Try to install the ng-sanitize version that works for your build

Answer (score 1):

if you are loading the resource from a local folder (static resource) please check if the path in the below statement (modified) is correct and the folder and the file exists.

```
require('./angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min');
```

otherwise if you are loading from a CDN resource as you are in your HTML you might have to configure your requirejs config object and map it to the CDN. The post below-

[Loading Bootstrap from CDN with Require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464846/loading-bootstrap-from-cdn-with-require-js)

Comment: i think the path is correct. Im also loading other modules from the same local folder, and they work fine.  I have also tried injecting 'angular.sanitize' instead of  'ngSanitize', still same error.

Comment: could you may be create a fiddle with your code which produces the error? it will be easier to investigate. thanks